# Best Way to make sure I'm not inserting information into the sqlite db that is already there?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm in the process of making a program that allows you to perform searches from the app. The App will then download the search results and store them in the database. I was using the url as the primary key so that I could make sure that I'm not inputting the same data twice (As URLs are sure to be a unique identifier), however this caused a few issues. The database would give an error and crash when trying to save a row with the same URL. I suppose this is good since I can put my insert statement in a try/catch block. I have some questions though:

1. What should I be catching (try catch block) to detect when an error like this occurs where the item it's trying to insert into the db is already being stored?
2. This is working with a simple "add each search result to the DB 1 at a time" approach. What if I wanted to do a database transaction and add ~25 at a time. How would I figure out which one was erroring, and what would be the best way to do this? Is there a way for it to continue on with adding the rest that didn't have the issue?
3. How would I go about doing this if I didn't want to use the url as the primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `INSERT OR REPLACE` http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: Assuming you actually do want to overwrite the old row with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could run a `select` on the table to see if the URL is already in there before trying to insert it.

But you should probably try to deal more gracefully with insert errors anyway.

Comment: Running a select on every row of data before I enter it enter would be a very inefficient solution. I'm sure better ways are available, I just don't know what they are. I think it probably has something to do with the try/catch. I just need to catch the right exception.

Comment: It's actually a very common approach. How else would you know if something exists before you insert it unless you check? If you have a lot of duplicates, I would expect catching the exception to be slower than running a select for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [unique index](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) or a [column constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint).